# Connect to VM that have same IP as host machine on Hyper-V

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have a dedicated server with Windows Server 2019 that I have installed Hyper-V on.
I have created a external switch and my first VM and the VM has a internet connection.
How ever, what I want to do is that I want a customer to connect to the VM i created via RDP through his own computer.
When I search "whatsmyip" on both my host and on the VM, they have the same IP.

So, how should my customer connect via RDP to the VM? If you connect to the IP through the RDP you get connected to the host server. I don't have any additional IP to assign to the VM, I only have one.

Emil

Comment: It sounds like what you need to deal with is port forwarding on the router that the host (and the VM) is connected to.

Comment: Whatsmyip will only show your WAN IP Address. You need to know the Local IP Address. Run ipconfig in a command prompt, and setup port forwarding accordingly on the router and/or on your VM host.

Comment: My dedicated server host said they dont block any ports. And I have opened the ports in the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the host and the VM access the internet via your router.
Services such as whatsmyip will return the IP address of the router,
so it will seem like they both have the same address.

This shouldn't bother you, as long as the VM does not need to be accessed
*from the internet*. Everything will work correctly, as long as the host
computer and the VM initiate connections *to the internet*.

If you wish both the host and VM to be separately addressable
*from the internet*, you will need to differentiate between them
by port number.

For more information about Port forwarding:

- Wikipedia [Port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)
- [How to Port Forward – General Guide to Multiple Router Brands](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/)

Comment: +1 finally someone seeing the WAN IP address that is not the same as LAN IP address.

Comment: Okay I think I understand.
Ive changed the RDP port of the VM to 3340 and opened this port in the firewall.
I don't know how I should open this port on the "router" aswell, becuase I rent this dedicated server from a hosting company.
Do I need to open the ports on the host machine aswell? Because right now it still dosen't work to connect via RDP to the VM.

Comment: You need to get in touch with the Support of the company you're renting from, as only they control the ports.

Comment: They said they dont block any ports.

Comment: They misunderstood - you should ask them about "port forwarding" and explain that this is for a VM.

Comment: They said that there is no need to port forward.

Comment: This is true for reaching the host computer, but not for the VM. There is a Windows solution if you only wish to reach the VM, but not the host - is this your case?

Comment: I want to reach both the host and VM through RDP.

Comment: You will need to explain to the Support your situation. If they still don't understand, ask to talk to a technician.

Comment: They told me they can't really help me out with the problem.
How ever I created a webhost on the VM and tried accessing it from an another computer using IP:80, but I couldent access it.
But then I setup a webhost on the dedicated server and then it worked accessing it using IP:80.
Its like the ports are blocked on the VM.

Comment: IP:80 is the host, never the VM. With port forwarding you could for example forward IP:8080 as port 80 *of the VM*. If the hosting company can't do port forwarding, you need to find another hosting company. Port forwarding is essential to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I see i see.. Thanks for your answers.
How ever, if I purchase additional IPs and assign a own IP for each VM. Would that work?

Comment: It won't work, since for the internet only the IP of your host exist. The ISP needs to publish the IP, and can't publish an IP of a (virtual) computer that doesn't exist for it.

Comment: I fixed my problem using netsh portproxy command on Windows for forwarding traffic on port 3390 to my VM.

Answer (score 0):

what I want to do is that I want a customer to connect to the VM i created via RDP through his own computer.  .....  [but]  they have the same IP.

Change the IP Address in the Hyper-V External Switch.  Your host and guest machines need to have different internal IP addresses.

If the guest is set up for static IP on the router, make sure it is a unique internal IP.

This is the best and most practical solution.

Make sure the computer trying to access has a different IP as well.

Doing this will separate internal IP addresses from the outside IP address (which should not matter).

Comment: the website whatsmyip.com will only show the WAN IP Address. Not the LAN IP Address. I'm sure the IP's cannot even be the same.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause is if the machines have the same name.  The network would give them the same number.  Also check that the hyper-v is not passing the same mac number through.  The name and mac number is what will do this.